# Facebook SDK not imprted in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have downloaded the facebook sdk version 3.21.1 and I have android studio version 1.0.2. 
Whenever I try to import the 'facebook' folder in the sdk folder(through the import module method), it dosent show up in the project tree on the left hand pane. Also I am getting this error : Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'pply()'
Possible causes:

The project 'The Social App' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For me I was having similar problems.

I am using Android Studio 1.1 and Facebook SDK 4.0.0

First, be sure to follow that steps 3  to 6 in the facebook developers page in your existing project. 
Click [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) for the getting started instructions.

Be very sure you follow it all. 
After importing it I didn't see it in my project structure be sure to click down on the left corner and make sure it is on Project, if not use    the drop down and select Project.

Also do `ctrl+alt+shiftt+s` to bring up the project structure wizard. Then go to app dependencies and click plus in the right corner to add the `:facebook` module dependency.

Then make sure that in your root project build.gradle that it's using **gradle 1.1.1** since some problems with importing has been fixed here.

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Then referencing this answer was the finishing touch:

[Can not import facebook-sdk 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581771/can-not-import-facebook-sdk-4-0-1)

Then a pop should appear to upgrade buildToolsVersions to 21.1.1.

This is what it took for me to get this all working. Hope it works for you too!