# Can not import facebook-sdk 4.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have android studio 1.1.0 and i just created a new project and i'm trying to import new facebook-sdk 4.0.1 but can not do this, I followed [Facebook Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

But can not get it work. My app structure [image]

My build.gradle(Project: MyApplication) file is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        //mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

My build.gradle(Module: app) file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hema.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
}
```

Finally the error message is:

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

**Edit** I added mavenCentral() in the repositories closure in build.gradle(Project: MyApplication) file but not working with same error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved the problem, It was in my Gradle settings >> Unchecked Offline work
[image]

Comment: This worked for me too, but does anyone have an idea why this has fixed the problem?

Comment: Because when you add line `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'` or any library like this android studio must to download require files from internet

Comment: I have the same issue but the offline work is unchecked.

In the console i can see it is looking for it in my SDK lib.

Answer (score 5):

Actually i got the same problem  and i solved it ..

**1** : File > Import Module ..find facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1 then Finish

**2** : Go to File > Project sturucture > dependecies tab > Module Dependencies select :facebook

**3** : SYNC project and Rebuild

IF you got error like Could not find property '**ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION** after rebuilding

go to ***facebook/build.gradle***  and change this part

```
compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
        targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    }
```

to your sdk version like

```
 compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral()` in the repositories closure in your build.gradle file and sync.

Comment: Where i will add `mavenCentral()` exactly ?

Answer (score -1):

Connect your laptop or computer with **Internet** connection.
It happened with me. I tried everything but at last when I commented laptop with Internet connection it worked.